# Merge Rails objects with equal attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with creating new records that potentially have the same (also newly created) children.
To make things easier, let's assume I have a table named `rules` (as in rules in an access control list for a firewall) and a table named `ips` containg a single `UNIQUE INDEX`ed attribute named `ip_str`.

In order to create a `Rule`, a source `Ip` and a destination `Ip` is required.

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :src_ip,  class_name: Ip.name
  belongs_to :dest_ip, class_name: Ip.name
end
```

It is not uncommon to use a `Rule` like `deny ip any any`, which in our case would be equivalent to

```
src  = Ip.where(ip_str: "any").first_or_initialize()
dest = Ip.where(ip_str: "any").first_or_initialize()
rule = Rule.new(src_ip: src, dest_ip: dest)

rule.save()
#=> throws error: duplicate entry
```

The obvious problem here is, that when I try to save the `Rule` and there is no `Ip` in the database with `ip_str = "any"`, Rails keeps two separate `Ip`-objects in memory and tries to save them after one another. So saving the first `Ip` succeeds, then it tries to save the second `Ip`, which it thought didn't exist yet, and ends up with an error, because of the `UNIQUE INDEX`. Is there a way to tell Rails to merge "duplicate" objects in memory before attempting to save?

An obvious solution to the example given above would be the following

```
src  = Ip.where(ip_str: "any").first_or_initialize()
dest = Ip.where(ip_str: "any").first_or_initialize()

dest = src if (src.ip_str == dest.ip_str)

rule = Rule.new(src_ip: src, dest_ip: dest)
rule.save()
#=> always succeeds
```

Sadly the real world is a lot more complex and I'm potentially saving a large amount of records at the same time in differenct child models. And yes, the `UNIQUE INDEX` is absolutely crucial.

Comment: Maybe it would be acceptable to you to use `first_or_create` instead of `first_or_initialize`? With that you save the first `Ip`, next you try to save another one (with equal attrs) and you just get the first one saved before. Two variables - one object.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, instantly saving a model object as soon as it is initialized would solve that. In that case, I have to wrap the whole code block, which is responsible for creating an object and its children in a `transaction`, so it can `rollback` smoothly; not sure if doing that also smoothly generates all the activerecord-errors, though, since it would abort the transaction as soon as the first error occurrs.

Comment: Glad that solution can be useful in your use case. Added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it would be acceptable it's possible to use `first_or_create` instead of `first_or_initialize` here.

So you save the first `Ip`, next you try to save another one (with equal attrs) and you just get the first one saved before. Two variables - one object.